# PrintPreview is generated after re-adding the usercontrol into the main page

Tags: printing, uwp, uwp-xaml

Today, I got a new problem while printing the uwp app, that the print preview could not be generated if I remove and then again add my usercontrol into the main page.

My scenario: I have a user control in which I have a listbox whose  items are horizontally aligned but I want to print these items (2 items per page) in vertical fashion.

So, I have created another same listbox with vertical aligned items and initially this listbox is hidden then while creating the preview this listbox is displayed for a while.

Now, the issue is for the very first time when I run my application then it works like a charm then after removing the same usercontrol and adding it again is creating a problem for me and the print preview could not be generated.

I have created a stripped down sample replicating this issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the application.
2. Click on "Load contacts" button
3. Click on "Print" button

Observe: A print dialog is opened and the print preview is created -- Correct

4. Now, cancel the printing process to hide the print dialog
5. Click on "Clear" button to remove the usercontrol
6. Now, repeat the steps from 1 to 3

Observe: This time, print preview is not created ---- Incorrect

Demo sample link:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiCx3o82H3zN9XD8iNCnaUmHUpzI

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Unloaded event , when you set the `null` to the `PrintManager` that you can not remove the PrintManager.PrintTaskRequested event from it. It will throw the "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."

You should be able to remove the PrintManager.PrintTaskRequested event before the `PrintManager` is be set the null.

For example:

```
private void ContactsUserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        printMan.PrintTaskRequested -= PrintTaskRequested;
        printMan = null;
        printDocSource = null;
        printDoc.Paginate -= Paginate;
        printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= GetPreviewPage;
        printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDoc_AddPages;
        printDoc = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```